# Running `scp` client -> server results in scp command not found (on server), why?

Tags: security, openssh

We've intentionally built OpenSSH using this switch: `--with-default-path` blank. We're attempting to deploy OpenSSH so that the server does not include the `scp` binary.

Now when we try to do an `scp` from a local machine (client) to a remote machine (server) we're getting this message:

> scp command not found

The server appears to expect the `scp` binaries to be present on both sides (client & server). So why do we need the `scp` binary on the remote end? Isn't it sufficient to only have it on the local machine (client)? Can anyone please clarify?

**NOTE:** If `scp` is not present on the remote server where we want to copy some file, it throws out an error like this on the remote (server):

> scp command not found

Answer (score 4):

I think you've answered your own question: you need `scp` on both sides.

The local instance of `scp` invokes `scp` remotely with the undocumented `-t` flag to handle the file transfer protocol.

If you really don't have `scp`, but you do have an `ssh` server, you might be able to use `sftp` to transfer the files, as in many cases the SFTP server component is built in to the `ssh` server.

Comment: so when remote scp also gets invoked, which scp actually copies the file contents from the source  and write to the destination ..These are scp/ssh logs on client side.....
  The issue I am facing is " when I set default linux path on remote server  to empty one, scp from outside to remote server doesnot work, as it needs default path of scp.. but scp from remote server to outside works..

Comment: "debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t /root
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
Sending file modes: C0644 853 temp.sh
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 24
temp.sh                                       100%  853     0.8KB/s   00:00
debug2: channel 0: read<=0 rfd 4 len 0
debug2: channel 0: read failed
"

Answer (score 2):

#### TLDR

The SSH protocol is facilitating multiple overlapping "services" of which file copying is one of them. The way the SSH protocol does this is by launching `scp -t` as a child process on a server, when a client connects to it using the `scp` command line tool.

Each server where SSH is installed requires a full compliment of CLI tools to provide all the "services" that are part of SSH (`ssh`, `scp`, `sftp`). There location on disk is only required by the managing `sshd` server daemon. This means they can be in any location, the clients are not aware nor need to be, they're only communicating with `sshd` via TCP port (typically 22) as client/server.

---

#### Background

Applications such as `scp` and `rsync` and `ssh` itself are client/server applications. This means that they require both a client application `scp` and a server application. In this case, `scp` is both.

#### Here's an example

```
$ scp /Users/user1/thumbnails-digikam.db pi-hole:/tmp/.
thumbnails-digikam.db                                                                                                                                   0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 scp /Users/sammingolelli/thumbnails-digikam.db pi-hole:/tmp/.
```

I've started a `scp` from my laptop to my Raspberry Pi server (pi-hole), and then paused it mid-stream via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

If I then `ssh` to the Raspberry Pi server and do a `ps`:

```
$ ps -eaf | grep [s]cp
pi        9688  6147  0 11:11 ?        00:00:00 scp -t /tmp/.
```

We can see that the application server `scp` is running, and writing our file to `/tmp` directory. We can see the file in this paused state being written as well:

*Rasberry Pi (server)*

```
$ ls -l /tmp/thumbnails-digikam.db
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 2260992 Jul  6 11:12 /tmp/thumbnails-digikam.db
```

*laptop (client)*

```
$ ls -l ~/thumbnails-digikam.db
-rw-r--r--  1 user1  staff  38551552 Jun  4 00:47 /Users/user1/thumbnails-digikam.db
```

If we let the `scp` continue by un-pausing it on the laptop (client):

```
$ fg
scp /Users/user1/thumbnails-digikam.db pi-hole:/tmp/.
thumbnails-digikam.db
$
```

It'll finish and if we look again on the Raspberry Pi (server) you'll see that the `scp` application is no longer running:

```
$ ps -eaf|grep [s]cp
$
```

OpenSSH is a bit unique in that it starts server applications (daemons) on demand just for the duration of a particular operation, and then once the transfer is complete, it terminates them.

The original daemon that's facilitating this is the `ssh` daemon:

```
$ ps auxf | less
...
root      6132  0.0  0.6  11524  5812 ?        Ss   02:53   0:00  \_ sshd: pi [priv]
pi        6147  0.0  0.4  11812  4016 ?        S    02:53   0:03      \_ sshd: pi@pts/0
pi        6150  0.0  0.4   6172  4036 pts/0    Ss   02:53   0:00          \_ -bash
root      6172  0.0  0.3   7232  3336 pts/0    S    02:53   0:00          |   \_ sudo -Es
root      6176  0.0  0.4   6120  4180 pts/0    S    02:53   0:00          |       \_ /bin/bash
root      9772  0.0  0.3   7888  3076 pts/0    R+   11:20   0:00          |           \_ ps auxf
root      9773  0.0  0.0   3800   480 pts/0    S+   11:20   0:00          |           \_ less
pi        9745  0.2  0.1   3988  1872 ?        Ss   11:19   0:00          \_ scp -t /tmp/.
...
```

Notice the parent/child hierarchy of `scp`, it's a child process of `ssh`.

#### Anatomy of a `scp` session

If you take a look at the [OReilly SSH book](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/ch03_08.htm) there's a diagram that shows the mechanics of how `scp` connections work.

[image: ss1]

In the diagram above, you can see that when the `scp <file> <server>:/<path>` command is executed, it gets translated to something like this on the client side:

> /usr/bin/ssh -x -oForwardAgent=no -oPermitLocalCommand=no -oClearAllForwardings=yes -- pi-hole scp -t /tmp/.

The client (`scp`) in this case is directing the `sshd` daemon on the client side to send a request to the server's `sshd` telling it to launch `scp -t /tmp` on the remote side.

Based on the documentation this is by design how `scp` uses SSH's tunnel.

[image: ss2]

#### Additional insights

I did some experiments where I made a copy of the `scp` binary to `myscp` and then ran this on the client. In every instance, the `/usr/bin/ssh ...` command still showed the `-- someserver scp -t /tmp/.`.

This leads me to believe that the name of the `scp` executable, though referenced by the `scp` client when the `ssh` command is executed, does not get passed to the client directly. Rather the `sshd` daemon has the names for the various client tools that it supports, hardcoded within it.

This is further backed up by the details shown in the able above.

#### Conclusions

It's not possible to completely remove/disable the definition of `--with-default-path` when compiling `sshd`. Removing it completely, breaks `sshd`'s ability to look for `scp -t <dir>` when an `scp` connection is triggered.

The best you can do to isolate `sshd` would be to designate a directory, which only contains the various binaries that make up OpenSSH.

#### References

- [OReilly SSH book](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/ch03_08.htm)

Comment: okay I got this point.But my doubt is when I execute scp from client and I did "ps -eaf" on client side and i got this process "/usr/bin/ssh -x -l root -- <SERVER_IP_ADDR> scp -t /root".so is this internal command(triggered by normal scp from client) is same as executing this command" ssh root@<SERVER_IP_ADDR> scp temp_file root@<SERVER_IP_ADDR>:/root" manually on client .I want to understand how sshd interprets this scp (first as well as second case mentioned above) and how sshd executes scp command..In second case,if we dont allow commands to get executed on server(like scp) from remote end.

Comment: will that affect first case also ? so are both the cases same ? Please let me know if I am not clear

Comment: @priyap - I now see what you're truly asking about, let me think about it and respond in a bit: your asking about this on the client server when you run `scp` `- /usr/bin/ssh -x -oForwardAgent=no -oPermitLocalCommand=no -oClearAllForwardings=yes -l root -- remotesrv.mydom.com scp -t /tmp/.`

Comment: @priyap - have you taken a look at this book by chance - https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/ch03_08.htm. Shows exactly what we're talking about there.

Comment: Thanks a lot ..This info is really helpful..I am trying to understand sshd code (in server perspective) , (i.e.,) how sshd interprets the scp command recevied from client(scp -t  bar) , whether its executing this scp command through  system or exec or fork..Please let me know if you come across this flow in sshd.

Comment: After authentication is succeeded, do_authentication API is invoked in session.c (openssh source code), but after that , how sshd executes command received from client is one thing am still trying to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

It's obvious, you must have protocol in both instance to use it.  If you want an alternative, can do with ssh as below.

```
ssh user@ip "cat > destination" < file.txt
```